# Send the requestbody of one API to another API

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here is my code

```
private static final String MEDIA_TYPE = "application/json";
    private static final String FORMAT = "UTF-8";
    private static String baseServiceUrl;
    private static String apiServiceUrl;
@RequestMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getMessage() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Started");
        try {
            messageProcessor.getMessage("test service");
              // Read from request
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String data = buffer.toString();
            StringRequestEntity requestEntity = null;
            HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
            int statusCode;
            logger.info("RequestBody"+data);
            baseServiceUrl="http://localhost:8080/services";
            apiServiceUrl="/services/rest/json";
            StringBuffer eventResponse = new StringBuffer();
            requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(data, MEDIA_TYPE, FORMAT);
            PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(baseServiceUrl+apiServiceUrl);
            postMethod.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
            statusCode = httpclient.executeMethod(postMethod);
            logger.info("Status code"+statusCode);

                } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Exception occurs ", ex);
            return new ResponseEntity("Internal server error !!", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity("Successfully called the service!!", HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

I want to get the requestbody of one API and send to another API .And a json is my request body.But in this code,I got the status code as 400.Can anyone help me to solve the problem

Comment: Is second  API is of same application or other?

Comment: not the same..other one

Comment: Did you check second url is working from direct call without passing authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have appended the /services in the url twice. It should be like:

baseServiceUrl="http://localhost:8080/services";
apiServiceUrl="/rest/json";

Comment: I have corrected it..But again got the 400 request code

Comment: If the apiServiceUrl is of different application than baseServiceUrl, you should have the full url for apiServiceUrl. And if you have access to the API code, check the path. Did you also check direct call from browser?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are reading the request body as a string , could you share the request body that is logged.The HTTP response code 400 corresponds to BAD request . So probably, either the endpoint that you are trying to hit is different or the request body has an issue. Try removing the `/services` from your `apiServiceUrl` to correct the url path.Also, since you are most probably having a json as request body try the following approach :

```
String json = "{"id":1,"name":"xxxx"}";
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
postMethod.setEntity(entity);
postMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
postMethod.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

make sure that the string that you read from the request using BufferedReader `reader = request.getReader();` is in appropriate json format.